# Connecting starting and ending points in a polar chart with ggplot keeping the position of the observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets start with the dataset, to make it reproducible:

```
structure(list(dataset = c(-23.8789646372585, NaN, -10.8009305417082, 
-11.8411770633881, -19.000246852629, -14.364572544966, -21.8175372410621, 
-25.4455825234135, -16.3659714913407, -24.2952691912406, -0.794961013892774, 
9.27790872080566, -20.9411764705882, -20.3132576468705, -25.1353910061732, 
-17.0200414318061), Tooth = c("UI1", "LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", 
"LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", "UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", 
"UM3", "LM3"), group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")), .Names = c("Comparison", 
"Tooth", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("UI1", 
"LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", "LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", 
"UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", "UM3", "LM3"))
```

As I want a specific distribution of the teeth in the radar chart, I created this vector, starting with `UP4` and ending with `UP3`:

```
order_teeth <- c("UP4", "UM1", "UM2", "UM3", "LM3", "LM2", "LM1", "LP4", "LP3", "LC", "LI2", "LI1", "UI1", "UI2", "UC", "UP3")
```

Then, I run this `ggplot` code:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=Tooth, y=Comparison, group=group)) + 
  geom_point(fill = "#F8766D", size=2.5, shape= 21, color = "black") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(order_teeth)) +
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position = position_identity(), color = "#F8766D", fill = "#F8766D") +
  geom_hline(aes(group=group, yintercept=0), lwd=1, lty=2, alpha=0.5) + 
  coord_polar() + 
  theme(legend.key = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray92"))
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a gap between `UP3` and `UP4`, which correspond to the starting and ending points. **How can I connect these starting and ending points?**

I've been reading in this forum some questions about this issue ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842249/join-gap-in-polar-line-ggplot-plot), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287409/scaling-the-axes-in-a-polar-plot-of-ggplot-individually)). However, most of them relied on rotating the labels. In my case, **I want the tooth labels to remain in its place**, but closing the upper gap.

This is another version adding `ylim(25, -40)` to the code. In this way, the gap is more evident at the top.

[image]

Comment: @aosmith do you have any idea or know somebody who can know the answer? thanks

Comment: Maybe something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26901499/2461552)?  If so this question may be a dupe.  (FYI you can't @ people who haven't commented on an issue; I just happened to have already been looking into it ;-) ).