# Wrong plotting of NA data in radar charts using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Dataset of this example, as codes to get the picture below [are in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205419/connecting-starting-and-ending-points-in-a-polar-chart-with-ggplot-keeping-the-p).

[image]

In my dataset, you will notice that LI1 has no data. When we plot in a radar chart, we see that LI1 is not represented by any point, as expected.

However, I would expect this gap to be from the radius of LI2 (which is the case) to the radius of UI1 (which is not the case). Instead, a line in between UI1 and LI1 is created.

So my question is: how can I edit the code to make this gap to go from LI2 radius to UI1 radius?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the right result is, but does removing the missing value from the dataset give you what you want? (i.e., use `dat2 = na.omit(dataset)` for plotting).

Comment: @aosmith. This is not what I meant, but surely does the trick. I think I am keeping this way. Thanks